# Cannot store strings correctly in Solidity Smart Contract using Web3

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, contract-invocation, contract-debugging

I am dealing with a very simple smart contract:

```
contract MyRegistry {

    struct MyEvent {
        string code; // service code, e.g. 1001/FOO/BAR
        string desc; // long string
        uint count;
        bool recorded;
    }

    event Record(bytes32 hash, string desc, uint count);

    function record(bytes32 hash, string code, string desc, uint count) external {
        if (registry[hash].recorded)
            throw;
        registry[hash] = MyEvent(code, desc, count, true);
    }

    mapping (bytes32 => MyEvent) public registry;
}
```

---

I then use web3's `getData()` for generating transaction payload:

```
var EthTX = require('ethereumjs-tx')
[...]
var calldata = Registry.record.getData(hash, code, desc, count)
[...]
var transaction = new EthTX({
    to: registry_address,
    gasLimit: 500000,
    gasPrice: +web3.toWei(10, 'gwei'),
    nonce: myNonce,
    data: calldata,
})
```

Transaction goes fine, but then, querying the `registry` through Remix, I see:

```
code: ""
desc: ""
count: 27
recorded: true
```

Strings have not been recorded!

---

I've also tried using `getData` in this way:

```
getData(hash, Web3.fromAscii(code), Web3.fromAscii(desc), count)
```

and in this other way:

```
getData(hash, Web3.toHex(code), Web3.toHex(desc), count)
```

but the result is even worse:

```
code: ""
desc: "<long hex string containing both code and desc strings>" 
count: 27
recorded: true
```

I cant understand what is happening. It is like web3 is not able to correctly serialize the payload and then, as a consequence, smart contract interface is not able to put the right number of bytes in the right "slots".

Any idea?

**P.S.** if I call the `record` method from Remix, with the same values, it obviously works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem.

The error is indeed what I was suspecting: the payload was not serialized correctly and, as a consequence, smart contract interface was not able to put the right number of bytes in the right "slots".

Reason? My bad...

`hash` is the first parameter of the `record` method. Also, `hash` variable is the result of a keccak256 JS library, **hex encoded**. Well, using `getData()` in this way:

```
contract.record.getData(hash, code, desc, count)
```

**is totally wrong**. `hash` is already hex encoded, but it is not `0x` prefixed. So `getData()` recognize it as a normal string, and converts it again to another hex string. What that means? that means the newly converted hex string **no more fits into `bytes32`**.

**Solution:** add `0x` prefix to `hash` in order to tell `getData()` that it is already an hex string (i.e. leave it untouched):

```
contract.record.getData(`0x${hash}`, code, desc,  count)
```

Also, there is **absolutely** no need to use `.fromAscii()` for the others two strings, as `getData()` recognize them as normal string because they are not `0x` prefixed, and so convert them to hex automatically.